# How does the first time multiplayer bonus work?

Tags: naruto-blazing

Every time I do a multiplayer mission, I get a first time bonus.

Is this because it's the first time I did a multiplayer mission on a certain stage? Or is it tied into playing with specific people for the first time?

How exactly does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a bonus to the first 100 multiplayer matches that you play in. I only realized this after I stopped getting bonuses and looked at a reddit thread about starting out that gives a detailed explanation of multiplayer and how it works.